# Loop through sections of a collection

Tags: c#

Here is a loop I'm working on to create a JSON object collection:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var list = DataAccess.Read.EventsByID(id);
foreach (var spevent in list)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("'{0}':'<a href=\"{1}\">{2}</a>',",spevent.StartTimeDt.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"), spevent.Link, spevent.Title);
}
```

The flaw is, if I have multiple events with the same date, I only get the last one because

```
window.eventscollection = {
    '07-23-2013' : '<a href="#">Item One</a>',
    '07-23-2013' : '<a href="#">Item Two</a>',
}
```

has two items with the same object name, and won't take duplicates.

The correct output would be to merge all items with the same date into one item as follows:

```
window.eventscollection = {
    '07-23-2013' : '<a href="#">Item One</a><a href="#">Item Two</a>',
}
```

It seems I need some kind of while or recursive loop to see if the next item has the same date as the current item and change the output, but I can't seem to get it right.

Thoughts?

Comment: Try to use LINQ `GroupBy()`, just group by date time

Comment: How would I then loop through a particular date range incrementally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could group the items from the same date as

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var items = DataAccess.Read.EventsByID(id).GroupBy(p=>StartTimeDt.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"));
```

then iterate through the grouping:

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
    StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(var subitem in item)
        sb2.Append(String.Format("<a href=\"{1}\">{2}</a>",subitem.Link,subitem.Title));
    sb.AppendFormat("'{0}':'{1}',",item.Key, sb2.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You first need to `GroupBy` on your list:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var list = DataAccess.Read.EventsByID(id).GroupBy(e => e.StartTimeDt.Date);
```

And then you can loop within the loop

```
foreach (var dt in list)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("'{0}'",dt.Key.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
    foreach (var spevent in dt)
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("'<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>',",, spevent.Link, spevent.Title);
    }
}
```